# Store records in a binary tree using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I want to store students record in a binary tree. I am implementing it in Python.

Student record will have three values,

```
StudentName, RollNo, Grade
```

Example,

```
John 4 A
Josh 2 B
Kevin 3 A
```

I can implement a single binary tree and insert single values there. But, to store student records, do I need to use three binary trees ? and then how to map the values ?

This is a simple B-Tree implementation in python with single value insertion.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = val

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

    def add(self, val):
        if(self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(val)
        else:
            self._add(val, self.root)

    def _add(self, val, node):
        if(val < node.v):
            if(node.l != None):
                self._add(val, node.l)
            else:
                node.l = Node(val)
        else:
            if(node.r != None):
                self._add(val, node.r)
            else:
                node.r = Node(val)

    def find(self, val):
        if(self.root != None):
            return self._find(val, self.root)
        else:
            return None

    def _find(self, val, node):
        if(val == node.v):
            return node
        elif(val < node.v and node.l != None):
            self._find(val, node.l)
        elif(val > node.v and node.r != None):
            self._find(val, node.r)

    def deleteTree(self):
        # garbage collector will do this for us. 
        self.root = None

    def printTree(self):
        if(self.root != None):
            self._printTree(self.root)

    def _printTree(self, node):
        if(node != None):
            self._printTree(node.l)
            print str(node.v) + ' '
            self._printTree(node.r)

#     3
# 0     4
#   2      8
tree = Tree()
tree.add(3)
tree.add(4)
tree.add(0)
tree.add(8)
tree.add(2)
tree.printTree()
print (tree.find(3)).v
print tree.find(10)
tree.deleteTree()
tree.printTree()
```

What is the recommended way to achieve it ?

I want to query like,

```
Get the rollNo where studentName='John'
```

Output :-

```
4
```

`Status (Fetch all the records)` :-

Output :-

```
John 4 A
Josh 2 B
Kevin 3 A
```

Comment: What trees (or structures in general) you use depends on what queries you want to make (efficiently).  You have to say what those are to decide.

Comment: Hi Davis, I have updated the question with the queries I want to make. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If the only key by which you need to look up individual records is the name, you can use one tree sorted by the name.  However, each node must *store* the while record.  You either introduce a type that has all three fields but defines `<`, `>`, and `==` (used in `Tree._find`) to compare only the name, or add support to `Tree` for using a custom *comparator* function.

The latter is preferable because it avoids establishing a strange meaning for the operators in other code; one function is enough if it implements `<`, because you can write

```
if less(val,node.v): # ...
elif less(node.v,val): # ...
else: return node  # equal
```